# Как работает тип RECORD в триггерной функции PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне необходимо логировать таблицы postgre, записи которых не имеют метки времени, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было получать по ним статистику. Решаю этот вопрос с помощью триггеров. В таблицу аудита записываю следующие поля: *<Имя_таблицы>*, *<Операция>*, *<Метка_времени>*, *<Записанные_значения>*.

Для этого использую:

`INSERT INTO audit SELECT TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, date_part('epoch'::text, now())::integer, NEW;`

Переменную NEW использую для того, чтобы не делать дополнительный запрос к оригинальным таблицам, а парсить эту строку и отдавать ее клиенту (некоторые таблицы имеют составной первичный ключ и не хочется писать лишние триггерные функции для этих таблиц).

Знаю, что переменная **NEW** имеет тип **record** и в документации про нее пишут следующее:

`Переменные типа record похожи на переменные строкового типа, но они не имеют предопределённой структуры. Они приобретают фактическую структуру от строки, которая им присваивается командами SELECT или FOR. Структура переменной типа record может меняться каждый раз при присвоении значения.` (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/plpgsql-declarations#plpgsql-declaration-records)

Насколько я понял из этого описания, запись из поля *<Записанные_значения>* не всегда будет соответствовать модели искомой таблицы. Проверил на нескольких тестовых вставках - записи значений идут в том же порядке, что и колонки таблицы. Вопрос, порядок всегда будет соответствовать или это какие-то частные случаи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные `NEW` и `OLD` при вызове триггерной функции всегда заполняются данными соответствующей вызванному триггеру строки (могут быть не инициализированы в зависимости от того каким именно триггером эта функция вызвана - `OLD` например не имеет смысла в `before insert`) и со структурой соответствующей изменяемой таблице. Это обязанность вызывающего триггер кода в базе ([например здесь](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/commands/trigger.c#L3091) при вызове `before row update` триггеров)

Представление `NEW` и `OLD` в триггерной функции в виде типа данных `record`, а не строгого объявления типа данных таблицы - условность. Это позволяет создать одну триггерную функцию и использовать её многократно с разными таблицами. Например, создать поле `updated_at timestamptz` в своих таблицах и заполнять с помощью `before update` триггера - поскольку имя поля одно и то же, достаточно одной общей триггерной функции, а не по отдельной функции на каждую таблицу.

При написании триггерной функции можно исходить из того, что переменные `NEW` и `OLD` являются типом данных обновляемой таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Но ведь в инструкцию INSERT в VALUE я могу передать значения не в том порядке, как идут колонки таблицы (указав порядок колонок в INTO). В этом случае так же будет записано через NEW в том же порядке, что и колонки таблицы? Я не силен в базах и хочу быть уверенным, что мои тесты не частный случай.